Hair particle is weird with rig. Not attached
Initially, I added hair particle on my model, groomed it and all. Then I made my armature and rigged my mesh. I know the armature should be the first in the modifiers and I placed it there. But the hair particle seems to not attach and rotate according to the faces of the mesh. I don't know where I went wrong
here's the model in initial pose with the hair

and here it is when I pose it.


Have you enabled Use Modifier Stack under the particle systems Emission > Source settings?

@GordonBrinkmann when i enable it the hair just disappears and doesnt reappear again when I disable it. :'>
